# React Beautiful DND nested drag and drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, react-beautiful-dnd

I am creating a side navbar with **react-beautiful-dnd**. The navigation consists of `pages` and `pagegroups`, the `pagegroups` consists of more pages and pagegroups we can add pagegroups and pages in any hierarchy we want in this sidebar.

[image]      [image]

[image]

Now I want to implement **react-beautiful-dnd** on this side navbar so I can drag and drop any page into a `pagegroup` or out of it anywhere I want in this side navbar. the drag and drop should be smooth.

**My solution:**

```
  const renderRow = (element, childNode, level_, key) => {
    return (
    
        {Array.isArray(element.children) && element.children.length > 0 ? (
          <Droppable
            droppableId={element._id}
            type={`droppableSubItem ${element._id}`}
            isCombineEnabled
          >
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
              <div
                ref={provided.innerRef}
                style={getListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
                {...provided.droppableProps}
              >
                {element.children.map((item, index) => (
                  <Draggable
                    key={item._id}
                    draggableId={item._id}
                    index={index}
                  >
                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                      <div>
                        <div
                          ref={provided.innerRef}
                          {...provided.draggableProps}
                          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                          {...snapshot.combineWith}
                          {...provided.combineTargetFor}
                          style={getItemStyle(
                            snapshot.isDragging,
                            provided.draggableProps.style,
                            item._id,
                          )}
                        >
                          {renderRow(item, true, level_, index)}
                        </div>
                        {provided.placeholder}
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </Draggable>
                ))}
                {provided.placeholder}
              </div>
            )}
          </Droppable>
        ) : null}
     
    );
  };

  return (
   
      <Droppable droppableId="dropable" type="droppableItem" isCombineEnabled>
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
          <div
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            style={getListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
            {...provided.droppableProps}
            onClick={() => {
              let documentObject = getObjectById(fileID);
              handleItemClick(documentObject);
            }}
          >
            {pageData && (
              <TreeView
                setExpanded={setExpanded}
                expanded={expanded}
                panelObject={panelObject}
                setAllowUseEffect={setAllowUseEffect}
                allowUseEffect={allowUseEffect}
                panelType="page"
              >
                {pageData.map((element, i) => (
                  <Draggable
                    key={element._id}
                    draggableId={element._id}
                    index={i}
                  >
                    {(provided, snapshot) =>
                      element._id != '' && (
                        <>
                          <div
                            ref={provided.innerRef}
                            {...provided.draggableProps}
                            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                            {...snapshot.combineWith}
                            {...provided.combineTargetFor}
                            style={getItemStyle(
                              snapshot.isDragging,
                              provided.draggableProps.style,
                              element._id,
                            )}
                            onDoubleClick={() =>
                              element._type !== 'page-group' &&
                              handleItemDoubleClick(element)
                            }
                          >
                            {renderRow(element, false, 0, i)}
                          </div>
                          {provided.placeholder}
                        </>
                      )
                    }
                  </Draggable>
                ))}
                {provided.placeholder}
              </TreeView>
            )}
          </div>
        )}
      </Droppable>
  );
};
```

The renderRow function is called used to render the children of in the pagegroup.

I have removed some extra code `dragdropContext` tag is used outside where this component is called. Now drag and drop is not working correctly inside pagegroups but are working fine
where there is no pagegroup I can even drag and drop the whole pagegroup it is dragging fine but the pages inside are not working as they should. The problem is that when I drag a page inside of pagegroup the other pages does not autoscroll and move to make space. this is not working as it should be